# Why does $\sin\phi=r\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ and $\cos\phi=\frac{dr}{ds}?$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

The relation between $p$ and $r$ where $p$ is the length of the perpendicular from the fixed point $O$ on the tangent to the curve at any point $P$ is called pedal equation of the curve.
I want to find the radius of curvature of the pedal curves.
Let $p=f(r)$ be the pedal equation.
$\psi=\theta+\phi........(1)$
 
and $p=r\sin\phi..........(2)$
Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $s$,
$\frac{d\psi}{ds}=\frac{d\theta}{ds}+\frac{d\phi}{ds}.............(3)$
Differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $r$,
$\frac{dp}{dr}=\sin\phi+r\cos\phi\frac{d\phi}{dr}$
$\frac{dp}{dr}=\sin\phi+r\cos\phi\frac{d\phi}{ds}\frac{ds}{dr}$
$\frac{dp}{dr}=r\frac{d\theta}{ds}+r\frac{dr}{ds}\frac{ds}{dr}\frac{d\phi}{ds}$
$\because \sin\phi=r\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ and $\cos\phi=\frac{dr}{ds}$
$\frac{dp}{dr}=r(\frac{d\theta}{ds}+\frac{d\phi}{ds})=r\frac{d\psi}{ds}$....from $(3)$
$\frac{dp}{dr}=r\frac{1}{\rho}$
We know that radius of curvature$=\rho=\frac{ds}{d\phi}$
$\therefore \rho=r\frac{dr}{dp}$

---

In this derivation i do not understand why does $\sin\phi=r\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ and $\cos\phi=\frac{dr}{ds}?$.Please help me.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand: what is $s$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati $s$ denotes the arclength of the curve, it can be interpreted as a parameter of the curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move along the curve from $P$ to a nearby point $P'$ with polar coordinates $(r+\delta r, \theta +\delta\theta)$. We denote the change in arc length $\delta s$. For $P$ and $P'$ sufficiently close together, we can assume that the curve between them approximates to a straight line.

We therefore have a triangle $OPP'$ with $OP=r,\; PP'=\delta s,\;OP'=r+\delta r,\; \angle POP'=\delta \theta\; \text{and}\; \angle OP'P=\phi.$

(Apologies for the lack of diagram — you may want to draw one!)

Now using the cosine rule,
$$
\begin {align}
r^2&=(r+\delta r)^2+\delta s^2-2(r+\delta r)\delta s \cos \phi \\
2(r+\delta r)\delta s\cos\phi&=2r\delta r+\delta r^2+\delta s^2 \\
2r\delta s \cos \phi&\approx2r\delta r \\
\cos\phi&\approx\frac{\delta r}{\delta s}
\end {align}
$$
And the sine rule,
$$
\begin {align}
\frac {\sin\phi}{r}&=\frac{\sin\delta\theta}{\delta s} \\
\sin\phi&=r\frac{\sin\delta\theta}{\delta \theta}\frac{\delta \theta}{\delta s} \\
\sin\phi&\approx r\frac{\delta \theta}{\delta s}
\end {align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is worth  going  back from differential to *finite difference segments*. The relations you ask are seen from trig *directly*.

Also curvature is defined as rate of change of tangential rotation with respect to arc $s$.

$$ \frac{   1  }  { \rho  }  =  \frac{ d \psi     }   {ds  }  $$

So the definitive relation you gave is incorrect.

BTW, rate of change of $p$ on arc is curvature multiplied by $\sqrt{r^2-p^2}. $

[image: DiffereceTriangles]